Mat-Tab hidden contrary to the set value
I do have a strange behaviour I absolutely can't explain to myself.
I hope anyone with more knowledge about angular and angular material components might have an idea.
In my Application at one point I use  <mat-tab-group>  with <mat-tab> in it's own component.
And i want to set the [selectedIndex] to 1 from outside. So I pass this value as @Input() 


export class SelectableMaterialNodeComponent {
    @Input() selectedIndex: number = 0;
}
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedIndex">
    <mat-tab label="First">first content</mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="second">second content</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>



Now to the weird behaviour.
After the page is loaded you can see the correct content for a fraction of a second:

And then it disappears: 
This is something I don't understand. If I now switch tabs manually the correct content is visible again.
Can anyone explain or does anyone have an idea what it could be that triggers this behaviour?
Thanks :)

issue not reproducible stackblitz

Check if you have a template reference variable called also selectedIndex, check if your parent change this variable, I've have no more ideas
